# ERROR in node_modules/@types/ramda/index.d.ts:373:64 - error TS1110: Type expected

Tags: angular, typing, ramda.js

When we run our build, we found the following error

```
ERROR in node_modules/@types/ramda/index.d.ts:373:64 - error TS1110: Type expected.
373     (<S1 extends string, S2 extends string>(s1: S1, s2: S2) => `${S1}${S2}`);
```

Answer (score 4):

We had the same problem and this is not ramda. You must update TypeScript to the latest version.

Answer (score 3):

In our package.json, we use

```
"@types/ramda": "^0.27.32",
```

But when I actually go into check the *@types/ramda/package.json*, it is 0.27.38

So I go back to my package.json in project and set

```
"@types/ramda": "0.27.32",
```

reinstall node_modules

It goes back

Answer (score 2):

You should update your typescript latest version.

Answer (score 2):

Update 2023

If you have this error `@types/ramda/node_modules/types-ramda/es/index.d.ts (4453:22)` with ramda.js v0.29 and `@types/ramda` v0.29 then update typescript version to v5+

From version 0.29 `@types/ramda` requires typescript minimum version 5